# Flutter how can I fill one edge of a container ? [ Toast notificaton container]

Tags: flutter, containers, toast

What I want to do is following left corner in the container.

I tried to do it putting another green container in it but, it does not fit with the border radius of original container.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 390,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.check_circle),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("YOUR MAIN TEXT"),
                  Text("YOUR TEXT"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was exactly trying to have!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting a `BorderSide` inside a `Border`.

```
Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 400,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green[200],
              border: const Border(
                left: BorderSide(
                  width: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image: Result]